# Arrays.sort() works different for int[] and String for same input why?

Tags: java, arrays, sorting

I was working on solving this problem from leetcode
https://leetcode.com/problems/largest-number/description/

I was looking at solution and noticed that sort behaves differently when input is number vs when input is a string(still number).

Input:

`[3,30,34,5,9]`

Code:

```
String[] numstoString = new String[nums.length];
for(int i=0;i<nums.length;i++){
    numstoString[i] = Integer.toString(nums[i]);
}

Arrays.sort(numstoString);
Arrays.sort(nums);
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(nums));        
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(numstoString));
```

Output:

`[3, 5, 9, 30, 34]`

`[3, 30, 34, 5, 9]`

Can someone enlighten me how is a "Number" different from Number when it comes to sorting.

Comment: Even if I think using ASCII VALUES for the sting version
[51,51+48,51+52,53,57]

Comment: How would you sort string in a dictionary? Using their integer value or the order of their characters in the alphabet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Number sorting is different that string sorting, when you sort numbers, you are actually comparing the values wherein, `3 < 5 < 9 < 30 < 34`, however when converting them to string, string compartison happens character by character by converting them into ASCII values, `34 < 5` because the first digit `3 < 5`

Comment: So String strictly compares one digit at a time ? i.e it ignores the leading ones? as long as the before digit is different

Answer (score 0):

In case of your `int[]` the numeric value is used to sort the list so 5 < 9 < 30...

In case of a `String[]` the numeric values of each character in the string is used to compare. So "30" comes for "5" because the ASCII value of "3" is lower than "5".